# Considerations when doing image classification where the object is not the subject

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition

I've come across two types of image classification tasks

1. **cat/dog classification** the whole picture is either a cat or a dog. Simple.
2. **this image contains a cat classification**. There's a whole chaotic scene, and the image may contain a cat nestled in there somewhere.

Type 2 seems to be way more prevalent in real life application. Here are just some examples:

- Determining the sex of an insect. Maybe the male and female look pretty much the same, but the male has a small bump in some location that takes up a tiny part of the image.
- Determining the presence of an animal call in an audio spectrogram.
- Finding defects in road surfaces.

My question is: for task type 2, what are some key modifications we'd make to the normal approach of post-training on an ImageNet trained architecture like Resnet? Shouldn't the architecture be modified somehow to be more fitted to task type 2?

Before someone mentions using object detection algorithms I'd like to add the rule that we only have global image labels, not bounding box annotation or co-ordinates of any sort.